# Select every row from Table A which are not in Table B

Tags: sql

I want to compare two tables and get all the records from table A which are not in Table B.

Here is an example

```
TableA
Articel ID                    
1                             
2                             
2                             
2                             
3                             
4                             
5                             
5

TableB
Articel ID                    
1                            
2                            
2
4                            
5
```

Then I want to have:

```
Articel ID                   
2                            
3                             
5
```

The Code below doesn't check for the number of entries and simply ignores all matching rows so that it would be:

```
Articel ID
3
4
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
    LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.ArticleID = B.ArticleID
WHERE B.ArticleID IS NULL
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What happens if there are four 2s in Table A and two 2s in Table B? Do you want one or two 2s in the output?

Comment: @maxu . . . I'm totally confused.  Your query will return duplicates in A.  What results *do* you want?

Comment: @maxu if there are 2,2,2,2 in table A what would be your expected results?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - they want `EXCEPT ALL` semantics

Comment: @forpas Table would be 2 2 3 5. I need to have this, because i want to sum up an other field, which is contained in table A, but have to eliminate these specific records when there are also records in table b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your RDBMS supports `EXCEPT ALL` you can just use that and you are done ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=890e3943ec66f516a6e9a43a639ee33d)).

```
SELECT "Articel ID"
FROM   TableA
EXCEPT ALL
SELECT "Articel ID"
FROM   TableB
```

Otherwise you can apply a `ROW_NUMBER` to number the rows then use `EXCEPT` if available (or any other means of doing an anti join if not available) - [db <> fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a884bcdc41707d9a822ef88a8a8db994)

```
SELECT "Articel ID"
FROM   (SELECT "Articel ID",
               ROW_NUMBER()
                 OVER (
                   PARTITION BY "Articel ID"
                   ORDER BY "Articel ID") AS RN
        FROM   TableA
        EXCEPT
        SELECT "Articel ID",
               ROW_NUMBER()
                 OVER (
                   PARTITION BY "Articel ID"
                   ORDER BY "Articel ID") AS RN
        FROM   TableB) T
```

Comment: It Works! But now i have the Problem, that i need 3 other rows from table A. Thought it would be easy, but EXCEPT doesnt allow me to add another row.

Comment: @maxu - three other **columns** not **rows** presumably. You need to explain from which row the column values are picked though. Probably best to do that as a new question as your original question is answered

Answer (score 1):

This should work in POSTGRES on the basis that you would require four 2s in A and two 2s in B to result in two 2s in your output:

```
SELECT
  ArticleID
FROM (
  SELECT
    TableA.ArticleID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableA.ArticleID) rowNo,
    COALESCE(t2.cnt, 0) rowsToAccept
  FROM
    TableA
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      ArticleID,
      COUNT(ArticleID) cnt 
    FROM
      TableB
    GROUP BY
      ArticleID
  ) t2
  ON TableA.ArticleID = t2.ArticleID
) t3
WHERE rowNo > rowsToAccept
```

Comment: Postgres supports a much easier way of doing this - as in the first example in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Swapped in more efficient solution, given you have a unique Column in both your tables.

Thought it was a fun problem, here's my quick solution that could inspire.

```
SELECT
  TableA.ArticelID,
  COUNT(DISTINCT TableA.ID) - COUNT(DISTINCT TableB.ID) As tblDiff
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.ArticelID = TableB.ArticelID
GROUP BY TableA.ArticelID
HAVING tblDiff <> 0
```

It will also tell you the difference between the two, i.e. how many are missing from one or the other. Idk about your data volume, so I didn't really put thought into efficiency.